# How to connect relational algebra(RA) Interpreter with sqlite3

Tags: jdbc, sqlite

I have just installed **RA interpreter** and i want to query from table that i have made in **Sqlite**.But i don't know how to connect both.After searching a lot i got some idea that there is **JDBC**
connection required for it and also replaced default **sample.db** with my database **first.db** in "ra.properties" 
as now becomes  **url=jdbc:sqlite:first.db**.Even after running  **\list;** command in RA Interpreter is not showing tables of first.db.Can someone tell what wrong i am doing and how to conect with **sqlite** ??

Comment: Are you sure that the database file is in the directory that happens to be the current directory when RA tries to open it?

Comment: yes,i have created the database first.db in the same directory where sample.db is and it is working with sample.db.

Comment: Just now i tried again and got the connection. Here i ran different code <b>java -ea -jar ra.jar sample.properties </b>. Edited sample.properties.